# Change lookup field value to current user's name upon opening record

Tags: lookup, user, field-update

I have a user lookup field which I want to be filled with the name of the currently logged-in user upon opening the record. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Chris, what you mean by saying 'opening the record', any select operation or display on UI?

Comment: Is this a visualforce page or standard page layout?

Comment: See this might help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17707/update-record-on-view

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following steps:

1. Create a formula TEXT field and paste below formula:

   HYPERLINK('/'+$User.Id,$User.FirstName+' '+$User.LastName)
2. Add the custom field in the page layout.